# How can I call validate on no change in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

## Set data that will fail validation

```
Model.set({phoneNumber : 'meow meow'})
```

## Validation that applies a border color

```
validate: function(attr){
    if(attr.phoneNumber){
        var phoneNumber = attr.phoneNumber,
            regex = /^\([0-9]{3}\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/;
        if(!regex.test(val)){
            View.showError('businessNumber');
        }
}
```

- Later the user `focus` on the input field, I remove the error styling
- The user doesn't change anything and the `blur` event is fired
- Validation doesn't run because nothing changed.

Comment: In `blur` you can set the respective `attribute` with the value, so that it tries to set attribute whenever user changes the focus. But tradeoff is, if user didn't change anything in the field then also blur with fire and will set the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reference your view directly from your model. This is a completely deep and fundamental violation of *the* core tenet of the Model/View/* design. When you call `set` and validation fails, the model will emit an `error` event (as of Backbone 0.9.9) which your view should listen for and respond to by updating the view accordingly. You may also alternately pass a callback to `set` to handle the error, but events are the better choice in most situations. Note that your model needs to actually return an error object from `validate`, which will refuse to update the data, so after the user fixes the input and `blur` occurs, the data will actually change. With your code as is, Backbone thinks the `validate` call succeeded since no error is returned.

In your view, here's some pseudocode showing how to translate the model's error object into UI warnings:

```
initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.model.on('error', this.showError);
},

showError: function (error) {
    if (error.businessNumber) {
        this.$businessNumber.addClass('error');
    }
}
```

As a side note, don't feel bad about being confused with how to use backbone for forms. The fact that out of the box `set` won't accept invalid data is a huge stumbling block and non-intuitive. There are plugins to help with both forms and validation (https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Extensions,-Plugins,-Resources), but out of the box this is not one of the obvious/easy parts of backbone.

Comment: This was just a brief typed up example, I actually do `return` and error. I just upgraded to Backbone 0.9.9 so I'm not familiar with this `error` event, can you provide an example of how that works? I never did feel right about calling the view from the model.

Comment: Is there a way of getting the name of the value which had an error. I don't want to have a huge litany of `if(this value)` when all errors receive the same treatment. Also, is `$businessNumber` pseudo code, or is that an actual reference to my element that backbone maintains?

Comment: As is the case with many backbone questions, the answer is it's all up to you. It makes sense for the object returned by validate to mirror model.attributes in terms of property names, but the value of those attributes is an error message like `{businessNumber: 'is invalid'}`. `$businessNumber` is pseudo code. It's up to you to map the error object back to the view manually. Or look into a backbone plugin that will help with this. https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Extensions,-Plugins,-Resources

Comment: I suppose I used the wrong wording, I meant `attr` not `value`. I want to know what the `attr` is. for example `$(attr).addClass('error')` where `attr` would be `businessNumber`. the IDs of my fields match the `attr` names to make it easier.

Comment: Right, so if you have a reliable convention that you model attribute names map directly to DOM ids or classes or input names, then that's how you get your error styles applied to the particular properties that failed validation. That sounds like a perfectly reasonable convention to me, but backbone itself has absolutely zero code to help you with that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22998/discussion-between-peter-lyons-and-patrick-robert-shea-oconnor)